# "Cannot ingress to a shared database" when trying to connect to Heroku shared PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to connect to my newly created Heroku Django app with psql:

```
$ heroku pg:psql                           
!    Cannot ingress to a shared database
```

Any ideas of what that is?

I have a shared Postgres database 20GB plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't connect directly to Shared database instances - that option is only available to dedicated PG instances.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I asked another question about Heroku with my initial problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558879/how-to-migrate-postgresql-data-to-heroku