# How to migrate PostgreSQL data to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I'm moving from EC2 to Heroku, and I got a shared database so I cannot use `psql` to restore the database.

Any ideas or strategies to move this?

The only option I can think of right now would be to dump the data in Django (they use JSON for that) and migrate.

I have a Django app and a 20GB shared PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#importing_from_a_backup

Comment: It's a shame that this method means that you have to put the data at URL, such as S3.   Is there a solution to push locally stored data up to Heroku?

Comment: @GreenAsJade not that I know of, you could put it in dropbox or something.

Answer (score 0):

First up, I'll just state I'm a Ruby guy not Python so can't talk authoritatively for Python but may be able to point you in the right direction.

To get data into Heroku shared DBs you have two options,

1. `heroku db:push` - May be Ruby only but allows you to push contents of local db (whatever it is) into your shared database on Heroku.
2. `heroku pgbackups:restore` - allows you to restore a dump of a PostGres database into your heroku db.

If you're already using mySQL then you could look at ClearDB addon as a solution - this permits direct access via mySQL tools.